# Histogram with logarithmic bins and normalized

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalize, bins

I want to make a histogram of every column of a matrix, but I want the bins to be logarithmic and also normalized. And after I create the histogram I want to make a fit on it without showing the bars. This is what I have tried:

```
y=histogram(x,'Normalized','probability');
```

This gives me the histogram normalized, but I don't know how to make the bins logarithmic.

Comment: `histogram` has an optional input argument to specify bin edges. Create a logarithmic set of bin edges and you’re done.

Comment: @cris Could you write the exact syntax please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different ways of creating a logarithmic histogram:

1. Compute the histogram of the logarithm of the data. This is probably the nicest approach, as you let the software decide on how many bins to create, etc. The x-axis now doesn't match your data, it matches the log of your data. For fitting a function, this is likely beneficial, but for display it could be confusing. Here I change the tick mark labels to show the actual value, keeping the tick marks themselves at their original values:

   ```matlab
   y = histogram(log(x),'Normalization','probability');
   h = gca;
   h.XTickLabels = exp(h.XTick);
   ```
2. Determine your own bin edges, on a logarithmic scale. Here you need to determine how many bins you need, depending on the number of samples and the distribution of samples.

   ```matlab
   b = 2.^(1:0.25:3);
   y = histogram(x,b,'Normalization','probability');
   set(gca,'XTick',b) % This just puts the tick marks in between bars so you can see what we did.
   ```

---

Method 1 lets MATLAB determine number of bins and bin edges automatically depending on the input data. Hence it is not suitable for creating multiple matching histograms. For that case, use method 2. The in edges can be obtained more simply this way:

```matlab
N = 10;         % number of bins
start = min(x); % first bin edge
stop = max(x);  % last bin edge
b = 2.^linspace(log2(start),log2(stop),N+1);
```

Comment: if i also wanted to add on top of this histogram an other one (which will be just another column of the same matrix) how could i keep the binwidth the same?

Comment: @nikos: With method 2, you can use the same `b` for both histograms. `b` determines the edges of the bins, and thus the bin widths.

Comment: and if i wanted to use the first method? because i cant really undeerstand hw the second one works

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct syntax would be `Normalization`.
To make it logarithmic, you have to change the axes object.
For example :

```
ha = axes;
y = histogram( x,'Normalization','probability' );
ha.YScale = 'log';
```

Comment: the ha.Yscale will make the y axis logarithmic right? so i must change it  to ha.Xscale in my case?

Comment: Yes if you want X axis to be logarithmic.